# Once Starlink is fully deployed how many satellites will be visible at any given moment?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite, starlink, satellite-constellation

So the GPS system has 31 satellites in an orbit of  20,180 km. Most of the time there are at least 3-4 satellites 'visible' (visible from a signal reception point of view) at any given moment.

The Starlink satellite constellation has many many more satellites (12,000-42,000), but at a lower orbit. To be useful there will need to be  at least 1-2 visible at any given time. However there could be more.

**Do we know how many Starlink satellite would be visible during normal operation?**

*Normal operation as a communication system; not just as the pretty satellite trains you get for a few months after launch.

Comment: My GPS receiver normally shows signals from more than 6 satellites at once.

Comment: @JonCuster Yeah there can be more. Although there are also the European, Russian, Indian and Chinese positioning satellites you may be picking up. The reason a say 3-4 is you need at least 3 to get a lat/long fix and 4 to get altitude as well. Although more is better!

Comment: just fyi: From Science Alert's [SpaceX Just Launched 57 New Starlink Satellites With Controversial Sun Shades](https://www.sciencealert.com/spacex-just-launched-57-new-satellites-and-scientists-are-worried-they-will-interfere-with-astronomy) *SpaceX already has permission to launch nearly 12,000 satellites, and last year sought additional clearance to put [up to a total of 42,000 satellites](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/spacex-starlink-internet-satellites-itc-filing-30000-additional-42000-total-2019-10) into orbit. And that's not counting other providers' plans.*